# How can I extract the value of JSON escaped as the value of another external JSON in Jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a JSON value that has the internal JSON value. How can I reach the "status" field of the internal JSON like that?

```
{"value":"{\"id\":17456,\"registrationTime\":1607604972797}","statusCode":"200","needUpdate":true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In the first JSON extractor, the escaped string was taken as the external JSON field and put into "plain_value" variable. The second JSON was extracted from that variable value 9. See the picture).